# User Trigger - Public Group Membership

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, user, bulkification

I need some help with a trigger. I want the role to dictate what public group a user is made a member of. I am trying to write this as a bulkified trigger using good SOQL form where there aren't any inside of loops. I can't figure however how to find a value in a list.

Can someone help me out?

```
trigger UserPublicGroupMembership on User (after insert, after update ) {

    List<GroupMember> gpMember = new list<GroupMember>();
    List<Group> pubGroup = new list<Group>([
        Select ID,Name 
        FROM Group
    ]);    

    //Put user in group if insert
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(User u:trigger.new){
            IF (u.UserRole.Name == 'BCS'){
                //Get Group Id from pubGroup list using Name. 
                Id GroupId = ???
                //Put both the group ID and User ID into the gpMember list
                gpMember.add(GroupId, u.Id); //??? Does this work ???
            }

            IF (u.UserRole.Name == 'BCS Manager'){
            //same process as for BCS
            }

            //so on and so on for all our roles. 
        }
    }

    //Check if profile or role changed, then put user in group if true
    if(trigger.isUpdate){

    }

    //Nnow that list is populated insert. 
    //Always doing an insert as system doesn't care about existing membership conflicts. 
    Insert gpMember;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple issues. First, you should adopt a trigger handler methodology. There are many out there, do some research and find one that works for you.

Next, see: [Parent and children relationships accessible via trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120577/parent-and-children-relationships-accessible-via-trigger) You need to update your reference to `UserRole`, because your current approach won't work. You can map them by name with something like:

```
Map<String, UserRole> roles = new Map<String, UserRole>();
for (UserRole role : [
    SELECT Name FROM UserRole WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT UserRoleId FROM User WHERE Id IN :trigger.new
    )
]) roles.put(role.Name, role);
```

You can do something similar for your `Group` records, though I'm not sure how you will filter them. Perhaps the naming convention is that they will have the same name as the `UserRole`? If so, you could do:

```
Map<String, Group> groups = new Map<String, Group>();
for (Group group : [SELECT Name FROM Group WHERE Name IN :roles.keySet()])
    groups.put(group.Name, group);
```

Once you have these collections, referencing them will avoid queries inside a loop.

```
for (User user : trigger.new)
{
    UserRole role = roles.get(user.UserRoleId);
    if (role != null)
    {
        Group group = groups.get(role.Name);
        // do stuff with this information
    }
}
```