# Trigger on CaseComment

Tags: apex, trigger, case, case-comment, parent

I'm trying to update a boolean field on `Case` called `Boo__c` when a new `Case Comment` is added to the `Case` and it contains the word `boo`.

```
trigger OHT on CaseComment (before insert,before update) {

    for(CaseComment c : Trigger.New) {
            if(c.CommentBody.contains('boo'))
                c.Parent.boo__c=true;

    }
}
```

I'm getting the null pointer exception:

Apex trigger OHT caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: OHT: execution of BeforeInsert caused by:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: ()

the field boo__c is on the Case object and I have access to it (I checked the Field Level Security)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just update related records in this way. You need to actually call `update` on a record. You [can't access parent fields in a trigger context](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120577/parent-and-children-relationships-accessible-via-trigger), but in this case you do not even need a query because you just need the `ParentId`.

```
Map<Id, Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>();
for (CaseComment record : trigger.new)
    if (record.ParentId != null)
        cases.put(record.ParentId, new Case(Id=record.ParentId, Boo__c = true));
update cases.values();
```

What's going on above?

- Take a collections based approach. You never want to perform queries or `DML Operations` in a loop.
- In this case, two `CaseComment` records could have the same `Case` parent. Since you would get an error for trying to update the same record twice in a list, use a `Map<Id, Case>`.
- You can update a record without querying for it if you know its Id. In this case, you're basically updating `new Case(Id=caseId, CheckboxField__c=true)`.
- You need to actually update the records. You need to work with a `List<SObject>` when making your `update` call, hence the use of `values()`.

If you want to filter on `RecordType` as well, you will indeed need to query. In this case, you will want to first collect the `ParentId` values that should be updated.

```
Set<Id> booCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
for (CaseComment comment : trigger.new)
    if (comment.CommentBody != null && comment.CommentBody.containsIgnoreCase('boo'))
        booCaseIds.add(comment.ParentId);
List<Case> records = [
    SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN :booCaseIds
    AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Some_Specific_RecordType'
];
for (Case record : records) record.Boo__c = true;
update records;
```

You should also look at [An Introduction to Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling) and add proper exception handling to your code.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for the tip I actually didn't know that you can't reference related child/parent on a Trigger.

How can I also check if the parent (i.e. case) has recordTypeId='01220000000FffjAAC' ? In that case I need to query the case like you mentioned, right?

Comment: Yes, then you need to query. I can update in a moment.

Comment: yes please do that would be great