# Workaround to avoid hardcoding the if condition parameters in apex trigger

Tags: validation-rule, customsetting, before-trigger, customlabel

I have a scenario to  write a good number of validation rules on a custom object. As I have to check the name field value of a lookup field using lookupfield__r.name in my validation rule, I am hitting the reference limit. Therefore I am  performing the validations in the before insert trigger.

Something like this:

> if(recordtypename == 'TestRT' && (lookupfield__r.name=='Value1' || lookupfield__r.name=='Value 2' || lookupfield__r.name=='Value 3') && PicklistField__c=='Not Applicable' && PicklistField__c== Null{
>           PicklistField__c.adderror('Error Message');
>   }

I have a few more conditions with different custom field combinations with lookupfield__r.name.

Can anyone suggest me a best approach to handle these IF conditions by avoiding hard-coding the values.

Here is how my hardcoded code looks like with multiple scenario conditions , in each scenario checking multiple fields of different datatypes:
 Here is how my hardcoded code looks like, can you help me on how to handle these multiple scenario conditions  `

```
If(trigger.isInsert){
   for(obj__C o: trigger.new){
       string   recordtypename = Schema.SObjectType.obj__c.getRecordTypeInfosById().get(o.recordtypeid).getname();
        if(recordtypename =='ValueRT'){
             if( (o.lookupfield__r.name=='value1' || o.lookupfield__r.name=='value2') && o.picklistfield1__c=='value1' && o.textfield1__c== Null){
                  o.textfield1__c__c.addError('error message');
              } 
              if(o.lookupfield__r.name=='value1' && (o.picklistfield2__c =='value' && o.picklistfield2__c !=null)){
                 o.picklistfield2__c.adderror('error message');
              }   
              if  (o.lookupfield2__r.name =='value'){
                   o.lookupfield2__c.adderror('error message');
              }
              if((o.lookupfield__r.name=='value1' || o.lookupfield__r.name=='value2') && o.picklistfield2__c =='Yes'){
                 o.picklistfield2__c.adderror('error message');
              }
        }
     }
 }
    `
```

Comment: [That won't work as you've written it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/120577/2995).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this can be done, but would need certain amount of reconstruction of your trigger code.

Before starting, I hope you are aware of following approach to get field values from an object:

```
List<Contact> conList = [Select id,Name,Account.Name from Contact limit 1];
system.debug(conList[0].get('name'));
system.debug(conList[0].getSObject('Account'));
```

To continue with setting up the dynamic validation rule:

1. Setup a custom setting/metadata with following fields

   - field name - Stores the api name of the field
   - expected field value - Expected field value for the record
2. Write a SOQL query to get all records in your code
3. Query the metadata and write a for loop to check all conditions

> ```
> List<Id,Boolean> recordValidatedList = new List<Id,Boolean>();
> Boolean isValidRecord = false;
> for(Contact con : conList){
>     isValidRecord = true;
>     for( iterate over all records in custom metadata){
>         String fieldName = //get from metadata record
>         String expectedValue = //get from metadata record    
>         if(con[fieldName] != expectedValue){
>             isValidRecord = false;
>           break;       
>         }
>     }
>     recordValidatedList.put(con.id,isValidRecord);
> }
> ```

4. Check in the **recordValidatedList** list to make sure that your record has passed the validation.

This is where I would start and gradually build it to support relationships.

Comment: Hi Salesforcesmarty, I have added the hardcoded code with the scenario's I am having. It would be awesome if you could help me in directing to handle multiple fields in my if condition using custom settings instead of hardcoding the conditions.Thanks in advance

Comment: That's what I have described in the answer. Give it a read and tell me what doesn't make sense to you.