# How to Update Lookup_field name on user object using trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

I have 3 objects:

1)User(field: UserTextField__c )

2)Project__c is the parent of object__c

3)object__c is child of user(fields: project__c(lookup), user__c)

In object__c for single user having single record (multiple records restricted) only. 
I want to display **project__r.name** of user on his user object custom field(UserTextField__c ).

I tried with the following code: It is displaying id of the project__c  in user's field(UserTextField__c).

**I tried with the obj.project__r.name but it is giving empty value.**

```
trigger UpdateFieldOnUser on Object__c (before insert, before update) {
    //id of user to update the field 
    list<id> userids= new list<id>();
    if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Object__c obj: trigger.new)
        {
            userids.add(obj.User__c);
            user usr=[select id, UserTextField__c from user where id =:userids];
            usr.UserTextField__c= obj.project__c; 
            update usr;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate: [Parent and children relationships accessible via trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/120577/2995)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a query in a `for` loop! But in fact, you do not even need to query for the `User` records. Just remove that query entirely. You do, however, need to query the records related by `LookupField__c`. This is bulkification 101:

- Collect Id values
- Query for records outside your loop and map by Id

That typically looks like:

```
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Object__c record : trigger.new)
{
    parentIds.add(record.Lookup__c);
}
Map<Id, Parent__c> parentRecords = new Map<Id, Parent__c>([
    SELECT Name FROM Parent__c WHERE Id IN :parentIds
]);
```

Then you would change your original loop to:

```
Map<Id, User> relatedUsers = new Map<Id, User>();
for (Object__c record : trigger.new)
{
    Parent__c parentRecord = parentRecords.get(record.Lookup__c);
    // because you already queried and mapped the records, no query required inside loop

    if (parentRecord != null && record.User__c != null)
    {
        relatedUsers.put(record.User__c, new User(
            Id=record.User__c, UserTextField__c=parentRecord.Name
        ));
    }
}
update relatedUsers.values();
// perform DML outside loops as well
```