# Salesforce Trigger to update a lookup field to a default value

Tags: apex, trigger

Below is the trigger I've written on Case that although did not throw any syntax error but does throw below error when trying to create a new case.

> Apex trigger DefaultPartName caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: DefaultPartName: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: T012390000001jvk: Trigger.DefaultPartName: line 3, column 1

**What am I missing here?**

The requirement is, anytime a new case is created for **specific Case Record Type**, it should set a Part Name(API Name: Part_Number__c )field to a default value called "Not Product Related" for any other Case Record type, No action should happen on the Part Name field.

Below is the Trigger:

```
trigger DefaultPartName on Case (after insert) {
    for(Case c : Trigger.new){
        if(c.RecordTypeId == 'T012390000001jvk'){
            c.Part_Number__c = 'Not Product Related';
        } else
            c.Part_Number__c = '';
        insert c;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that the [`Apex Developer Guide`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) explicitly recommends using a `before` trigger for field updates:

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

---

The key prefix (first three characters) for *every* `RecordType` is `012`, not `T01`. You seem to have prepended a `T` to the Id value for some reason. But you should not hardcode your ids anywhere. It is bad practice and will not work when you migrate between environments.

---

Much better to use describes or queries to get the Id. *Never* hardcode the value.

```
Id myRecordTypeId = SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
    .get('My Record Type').getRecordTypeId();
for (Case record : trigger.new)
{
    if (record.RecordTypeId == myRecordTypeId)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

---

Another note, if `Part_Number__c` is a **Lookup** field, you need to set the Id of the parent, just like you do when reading the `RecordTypeId` value. Note that you don't check `RecordTypeId = 'Some Record Type Name'`, but rather check the actual Id value. It's the same with all lookups, whether getting or setting via code.

```
MyRelatedObject__c relatedObject = [SELECT Id FROM MyRelatedObject__c WHERE Name = ''Not Product Related'];
```

Note also you will need to *create this record* in your unit test before running your trigger.

---

Note that this line in an after insert trigger is going to throw errors and completely unnecessary:

```
insert c;
```

Remove this line. The record is *already being inserted*.

Comment: its an after insert trigger. inserting explicitly by insert c; is not required?

After changing from RecordTypeId to RecordType.Name and I'm now getting  following error:

Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger DefaultPartName caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: DefaultPartName: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: : Trigger.DefaultPartName: line 6, column 1 –

Comment: @sfdcDev Is `Part_Number__c` a lookup? If so then you need to actually set the Id of the corresponding record, not its name...

Answer (score 3):

The value you've got in quotes is not a valid id. They're either 15 or 18 characters.

RecordType records have a prefix of `012`, so in theory if you delete the `T` you'll be in good shape - assuming that is a valid id in your org.

It would be better though to not hardcode the `id` value at all and either query for it using SOQL or use a describe call.

Comment: Except `c.RecordType.Name` [will always be null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/120577/2995) in the trigger context.

Comment: details, details :-)

Comment: so I've changed from  RecordTypeId to RecordType.Name and it still throws the following error:
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger DefaultPartName caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: DefaultPartName: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: : Trigger.DefaultPartName: line 6, column 1

Comment: Below is the revised trigger:

'trigger DefaultPartName on Case (after insert) {
    for(Case c : Trigger.new){
        if(c.RecordTypeIName == 'TABS Support'){
            c.Part_Number__c = 'Not Product Related';
        } else
            c.Part_Number__c = '';
        insert c;
    }

}'