# How to retrieve Parent's Id of a triggered child record, inside the trigger - Solved

Tags: after-trigger

Certification__c(Parent object) --> Exam__c(Child object)
Trigger triggers when Child is updated.

```
trigger certificationToFailedNew on Exam__c (after update) {
    //List out all the exams associated with the parent of the triggered object. exam record -> ParentID -> other child records which share the same parent
    List<Exam__c> exams = new List<Exam__c>();
    exams = [
        SELECT Id,Exam_id__c, Exam_state__c, Certification__r.Id, Certification__r.Exam_state__c
        FROM Exam__c
        WHERE Exam_state__c in ('Failed') AND Certification__r.Exam_state__c in ('Active') AND Certification__r.id == Certification__c.id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()
            AND id != id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()];
```

I'm trying to filter out child records(Exam__c), which share the same parent(Certification__c) of the triggered child record. Or the siblings of the triggered record (other records which share the same parent)

What needs to be changed in my code @ 'WHERE' to get the required records only.

**Working UPDATED CODE**

```
trigger certificationToFailedNew on Exam__c (after update) {

    set<id> certificationId = new set<id>();
    String x;
    String y;

    for(Exam__c e : Trigger.new){
        certificationId.add(e.Certification__c);
        x = e.Exam_id__c;
        y = e.Exam_state__c;
    }

    List<Exam__c> exams = new List<Exam__c>();
    exams = [
        SELECT Id, Exam_id__c, Exam_state__c, Certification__r.Id, Certification__r.Exam_state__c
        FROM Exam__c
        WHERE Exam_state__c in ('Failed') AND Certification__r.Exam_state__c in ('Active') 
            AND Id NOT IN :trigger.newMap.keySet() AND Certification__r.Id IN :certificationId 
            AND Exam_id__c = :x AND Exam_state__c = :y];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid SOQL syntax.

```
    WHERE Exam_state__c in ('Failed') AND Certification__r.Exam_state__c in ('Active') 
        AND Certification__r.id == Certification__c.id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()
        AND id != id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()];
```

Additionally, the values in `Trigger.newMap().keySet()` are `Exam__c` Ids. You cannot filter `Certification__c` Ids against them.

Instead, you need to loop over the trigger objects to accumulate a `Set<Id>` of the Ids of the parent records whose other children you wish to filter.

Then, both of your `AND` clauses are replaced by

```
Certification__c NOT IN :setOfParents
```

That will exclude all siblings of the current records (as well as the current records themselves), as it sounds like you want. If you wanted to get *only* siblings, you'd reverse the Boolean and add another clause:

```
    Certification__c IN :setOfParents AND id NOT IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()
```

Comment: AND id NOT IN :trigger.newMap.keySet() AND Certification__r.id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()];

Will this work? this is not showing an error. Or do i have to use the set class?

Comment: @NivethKumar No. That still filters against the wrong type of Id, as discussed in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, also i found this upvoted 14 times. List<Child__c> children = [
    SELECT Name
    FROM Child__c
    WHERE Parent__c IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()
]; @https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120577/parent-and-children-relationships-accessible-via-trigger ----- is this the same thing? can you guide me a bit on how to write the set class for my need.

Comment: @NivethKumar That doesn't solve your problem. Your trigger is on the child, not the parent.

Comment: thank you for the help, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent record id first you need to iterate over the trigger and add the parant id in one set.

```
trigger certificationToFailedNew on Exam__c (after update) {
    set<id> certificationId = new set<id>();
    for(Exam__c e : Trigger.new){
        certificationId.add(e.Certification__c);
    }
    List<Exam__c> exams = [SELECT Id,Exam_id__c, Exam_state__c,Certification__r.Id, 
                           Certification__r.Exam_state__c FROM Exam__c 
                           WHERE Exam_state__c = 'Failed' AND Certification__r.Exam_state__c = 'Active'
                           AND Certification__r.id  IN :certificationId AND id NOT IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()];
}
```

Comment: set<id> certificationId = new set<id>(); for(Exam__c e : Trigger.new){ certificationId.add(e.Certification__r.Id); } ***** is this correct, your code shows me an error?

Comment: certificationId.add(e.Certification__c);  **e.Certification__c and e.Certification__r.Id Both are same**

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: check the updated code, it is not executing what I want it to do when triggered. I do not get any errors, but i need to find a duplicate entry of the triggered record and then update the parent record. which is not working.

Comment: fixed it, thank you for the help